# I want to copy Content from one html Doc to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I'm new to the coding world and I basically have one query. I've created two html docs, `index.html` and `index1.html`

I've managed to make these two link with my css and js so that both index files use one set of assets, but I want to copy the content from index1 and place it inside of index.html.

When I do this, the content isn't like it was when it was in my index1 file. The whole look changes and my content is spread out everywhere.

What am I doing wrong? Obviously copy paste is not an option here.

Comment: Please show us some code so we can identify your issue.

Comment: We'd be glad to help, but we cannot do that if you do not show the code.

Answer (score 0):

If something like this:

```
<html><body><p>something</p></body></html>
```

is turning into

```
<html>
    <body>
         <p>
             something
         </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then everything is fine. You editor just supports automatic code formatting and makes your code in theory easiert to understand. Additional white space caracters like space and tab are normally not affecting anything within a html file.